# Why is this bat file not returning to the calling bat file?

Tags: windows-10

```
K:\bin>type get_resolution.bat  
i_view.bat "%1" /info=info.txt  
echo after get_resolution  
type info.txt | find "Resolution"  

K:\bin>type i_view.bat  
echo %*  
echo %errorlevel%  
echo after i_view  

K:\bin>get_resolution.bat input.jpg  

K:\bin>i_view.bat "input.jpg" /info=info.txt  

K:\bin>echo "input.jpg" /info=info.txt  
"input.jpg" /info=info.txt  

K:\bin>echo 0  
0  

K:\bin>echo after i_view  
after i_view  

K:\bin>
```

Why no "after get_resolution"?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `call` command.  Without using this command, the batch file will "replace" the current one.

In your script, you'd put `call i_view.bat "%1" /info=info.txt`.

`cmd.exe /k` is equivalent.

---

Here's part of the help text from `call /?`.

```
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

  batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
                     batch program.

If Command Extensions are enabled CALL changes as follows:

CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL.  The syntax
is:

    CALL :label arguments

A new batch file context is created with the specified arguments and
control is passed to the statement after the label specified.  You must
"exit" twice by reaching the end of the batch script file twice.  The
first time you read the end, control will return to just after the CALL
statement.  The second time will exit the batch script.  Type GOTO /?
for a description of the GOTO :EOF extension that will allow you to
"return" from a batch script.
```